# Validate Form Based on Hidden Input's Template Value - Is It Possible?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form that in layman's terms, has a bunch of buttons (that act like checkboxes) with values. Users can select a handful of buttons.
The buttons push their values (via a JQuery function) into a hidden input which I'm using to gather the values.

I would like to make sure that the `"values="` attribute of each hidden input isn't `null` or `""` when the user presses the submit form.

Ex: Make sure that the input **does NOT** equal this:

`<input autocomplete="off" id="id_valuePlatform" name="valuePlatform" type="hidden">` **or**

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="id_valuePlatform" name="valuePlatform" type="hidden" value="">
```

Here's the forms.py:

```
class getGames(forms.Form):
    valuePlatform = forms.CharField(required=True, error_messages={'required': 'You need to tell us your platform(s)!'}, widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'off'}))
```

Template:

```
<form method= "POST" autocomplete="off"> {% csrf_token %} 
          {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <div class="container">
            {% if form.valuePlatform.errors %}
                <ol>
                {% for error in form.valuePlatform.errors  %}
                    <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ol>
            {% endif %}
            </div>
                   {{ form.valuePlatform }}
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Views.py:

```
from .forms import getGames        
def find(request):
    form = getGames()
    context = {"form": form}

    if form.is_valid():
        print form.cleaned_data['valuePlatform']
```

Is this even possible, or would I have to pass the data to Django via a Ajax POST?

Comment: It doesn't matter to Django whether the form value is set using JavaScript or not. The above example should work. If it isn't working, then printing `request.POST` and `form.errors` in your view might help you see what data you are submitting.

Comment: It does work, but I would like the form to throw an error when the value is nothing or null.

Comment: Have you checked whether the message appears in `form.errors`? How are you displaying the firm errors in the template? Have you looked at the [rendering form errors docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages)?

Comment: @Alasdair I edited the original post with a piece of my template.

Comment: @Alasdair That was just a mistake. 
I thought form errors were generated automatically, and I would like it to pull the error from the `error_messages` in my form. Also, when the submit button is pressed and the `values=""` I get a `post` in my console. Which should be stopped if the form was making sure the values weren't nothing. I would think.

Comment: Django doesn't validate fields before the form is submitted, it validates the forms when you call `form.is_valid()`. If a required field is empty, then it isn't included in the post request, and the error message will be displayed in the template if your view and template are correct. If you want to prevent the form from being submitted when a field is empty, you'll need to write some JavaScript. Browsers with HTML5 validation will check fields with a `required` attribute, but I'm not sure how that will interact with a hidden field, and I don't think you can specify the error message.

Comment: @Alasdair Can you make an example of this for a view. I updated the original post with a quick example I made, however, no form errors appear still.

Comment: @Alasdair So are you saying that I would be better off just using a javascript and pass the data to django using ajax instead of a django form?

Comment: All I'm saying is that Django will not validate the data until you submit it. Whether or not you submit it with Ajax or not is a separate issue, I'm not recommending one way or the other.

Comment: Validating after submission is fine, but my `if form.is_valid():` isn't working.

Comment: You haven't bound the form to post data. See the docs on [working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Changed views.py to this, after looking at @ Alasdair's examples in the documentation:

```
from .forms import getGames        
def find(request):    

    form = getGames(request.POST or None)
    context = {"form": form}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
             print form.cleaned_data['valuePlatform']
```